# How can obtain mac address of the system where the application is to be installed?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reliable method to get machine's MAC address in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c)

I want to obtain the mac address of the system through code in the application program so i can use it to authorize at the system level ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908926/read-mac-address-and-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850650/reliable-method-to-get-machines-mac-address-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157246/getting-mac-address-c and so many more.

Comment: "the" mac address? The address returned from Me Disappointment's answer might be the address of a wireless card temporarily attached to the machine just during installation. There's no 1-1 mapping between mac addresses and systems, so using it as an authorization or authentication mechanism is a very poor choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via the active [network interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx), such as:

```
var mac =
    (from item in NetworkInterface.GetAllInterfaces()
    where item.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
    select item.GetPhysicalAddress()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Failing retrieval from an active interface, you might consider just grabbing the loopback address. Also, you could loop the elements as opposed to using Linq, should you wish to.