# Formatting MAC address in C#

Tags: c#, string, format, mac-address

In my C# application, I want to get my MAC address by using `NetworkInterface` class as the following:

```
NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
{
    mac = nic.GetPhysicalAddress()
}
```

But this code returns the MAC without ':' or any other separator.

How can I retrieve the MAC in this format:
`88:88:88:88:87:88`
**using the code above ONLY?**

Comment: "using the code above ONLY"? If that doesn't return the MAC address with any separators... you can't use that only.

Comment: I want to format it. do you have an idea how?

Comment: @gln - check d answer where i formatted the mac address

Answer (score 38, accepted):

try

```
mac = string.Join (":", (from z in nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes() select z.ToString ("X2")).ToArray());
```

Comment: in .NET 4 it can be even shorter `mac = string.Join (":", nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes().Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));`

Comment: Or: `mac = string.Join (":", Array.ConvertAll(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes(), b => b.ToString("X2")));`

Answer (score 4):

The help for the command shows one way:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.physicaladdress.aspx

```
    PhysicalAddress address = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress();
    byte[] bytes = address.GetAddressBytes();
    for(int i = 0; i< bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        // Display the physical address in hexadecimal.
        Console.Write("{0}", bytes[i].ToString("X2"));
        // Insert a hyphen after each byte, unless we are at the end of the 
        // address.
        if (i != bytes.Length -1)
        {
             Console.Write("-");
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: This can be done even shorter: `BitConverter.ToString(byte[])` does exactly this formatting.

Comment: @eFloh: Post that as an answer.

Comment: @BoltClock: This is already in the post linked below and only applies to this post, as it doesn't produce the requested output. See [this answer to Getting MAC Address C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157246/getting-mac-address-c/3157309#3157309) for an actual response.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [comment by eFloh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384211/formatting-mac-address-in-c-sharp#comment8916151_7384255) for using [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx) I was able to do the following (assuming `mac` is predefined as a string).

```
foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    mac = BitConverter.ToString(nic.GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes()).Replace('-', ':');

    //Do whatever else necessary with each mac...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
// Insert Colons on MAC
string MACwithColons = "";
for (int i = 0; i < MAC.Length; i++) {
  MACwithColons = MACwithColons + MAC.Substring(i, 2) + ":";
  i++;
}
MACwithColons = MACwithColons.Substring(0, MACwithColons.Length - 1); // Remove the last colon
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you want to show that, you have to do this:

```
txtMac.text=getFormatMac(GetMacAddress());
public string GetMacAddress()

{
    NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
    String sMacAddress = string.Empty;
    foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in nics)
    {
         if (sMacAddress == String.Empty)// solo retorna la mac de la primera tarjeta
         {
              IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
              sMacAddress = adapter.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
          }
    }
    return sMacAddress;
}

public string getFormatMac(string sMacAddress)
{
    string MACwithColons = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < macName.Length; i++)
    {
        MACwithColons = MACwithColons + macName.Substring(i, 2) + ":";
        i++;
    }
    MACwithColons = MACwithColons.Substring(0, MACwithColons.Length - 1);

    return MACwithColons;
}
```