# Im get the value like this from a return fuction now i want the string like

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Private Function GetMAC() As String
Dim macAddresses As String = ""
For Each nic As NetworkInterface In NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
    If nic.OperationalStatus = OperationalStatus.Up Then
        macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString()
        Exit For
    End If
Next
    Return macAddresses
End Function


Dim str As String = GetMAC()
MsgBox(str)
```

str  values comes as F406697228D3
now i want change this as F4-06-69-72-28-D3..?

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384211/formatting-mac-address-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `For` loop like this:-

```
 Public Function GetFormattedString(input As String) As String
        Dim result As String = String.Empty
        For index = 0 To input.Length Step +2
            result += input.Substring(index, Math.Min(2, input.Length - index)) + "-"
        Next
        Return result.Trim("-")
 End Function
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yndQUy) for your reference.