# Get machine's mac address c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to get user's MAC address. After some research, I found this code:

```
string GetMacAddress()
{
    string macAddresses = "";
    foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
    {
        if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
            continue;
        if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
        {
            macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
            break;
        }
    }

    return macAddresses;
}
```

There are no errors but I always get an empty address. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: This code weon't give you the user's address but your own (server's) address. Have you tried debugging your code to check the results of `NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` ?

Comment: check this answer that might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157246/getting-mac-address-c-sharp/3157288#3157288

Answer (score 8):

> I'm workin on an mvc .net application and I want to get user's mac address.

You can forget about it, that's not possible. You can get only the IP address of the client that is browsing your website.

Actually there is one way to get it. Add the following in your view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Label("Mac", "Please enter your MAC address")
    @Html.TextBox("Mac")
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and inside the corresponding controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(string mac)
{
    // if the user was kind enough to provide you his MAC address
    // you could read it from the mac argument
    // Of course he could have entered any MAC address he likes and
    // you have no way of verifying that
    ...
}
```

Yet another possibility is to develop an ActiveX control (that will work only under IE) and that the user can install in his browser which could retrieve the MAC address of his NIC and send it to the server.

Comment: Just an addition: If you want to get a MAC Address from a client computer, you need to use ActiveX/Java or something similar.

Comment: Yes...you can get the IP address, and even this sometimes only resolves to their router, firewall etc...even sometimes the ISP. Therefore you are unlikely to be able to resolve the IP address to the client machines MAC address.

Comment: @FilipEkberg, that is in fact true. Would you recommend that type of approach?

Comment: @Mike, No. As there's no reason to get the MAC

Comment: @FilipEkberg, I'm glad that was your answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted will get the MAC address of the machine hosting the site, not the users MAC address. It's virtually impossible to get a remote MAC address unless you have some software running on their machine that will report it back to you.

Failing that, you could look into getting their public IP address and resolving that to MAC. I have done this in the past (how...I cannot remember, it was in my "hacking" days long ago!). As I said, this will get the MAC resolution of the public IP address (router, firewall etc).

There is a list of IANA assigned MAC addresses somewhere on the internet which lists which MACs have been assigned and to which company, that might be useful to you as well.

Ethically I think it's not a good idea to get a user's MAC address as its the one unique thing pointing to their machine, and their machine only!

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be your problem;

```
 if (nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet) continue;
```

as most current connections will be

```
 NetworkInterfaceType.GigabitEthernet
```

Just include it into the selection

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterfacetype.aspx

Comment: He is asking about the MAC address of the client, not that of the server.

Comment: Still I think I answered his question why he get's an empty address. Even if it will be a different address from the one he wants in the end.